# Is it possible to remove queued item in hosted build agent in Team Services (previously VSO)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a basic `ASP.NET CORE` project. To achieve CI and CD I've used Team Services for quite some time now, but yesterday for some reason the deployment went wrong (happened more often). But when I tried to redeploy the latest build to the server the hosted Team Services build agent didn't pick it up from the queue.

Also when I tried to trigger another build it just gets stuck in the queue
[image]

Here is the history of the release that failed
[image]

What the release definition does it first stops the webserver, then starts it back up and finally deploys the website.

Now I've searched if it's possible to reset the queue or reset the agent, but so far no luck. Does anyone here have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having contact with a Technical Evangelist from Microsoft he told me there was nothing I could do. This happens in rare cases and needs to be fixed by them. So the only solution is to enter a support ticket